# Facebook App Requests shows no friends (infinite loading)

Tags: facebook, api, apprequests, invite

I've been trying everything to fix this issue.

I have setup a basic php based Facebook App (Canvas/iFrame) - and it loads fine, asks for permissions and installs ok.

I've tried the apprequests code on the Developer site, plus different examples to try and invite friends to the app.

The dialogue box does show, but the loading bar just runs without showing any friends to select.

The code I'm using is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<button id="send-to-many">Send App request</button>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '<?php echo $appid ?>',
  });
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'You should learn more about the Platform.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response) {
alert('invited');
    } else {
alert('not invited');
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Not sure how to get around this. Any ideas!

I can however add a "to" in the method and specify a single user ID and that works.

So am thinking it could be a permissions issue?

Many thanks,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a permissions issue - a lot of the dialogs are designed to be used without having to auth an app.

I've just run this exact code, replacing the app ID with mine, and it works. So some things to check are:

- Are you getting any JS errors in the console?
- Is the app in Sandbox mode and you're using it with a non-admin user?
- Has the account you are using definitely got friends?

Comment: Hi Joe T,
Thanks for your answer - I'm guessing it might be the way my app has been setup?

https://apps.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/apprequest/first_degree.php?viewer=656835525&app_id=232695683503632&token=v7&__user=656835525&__a=1

and this generates a 500 error

- The app isn't in Sandbox mode and I'm using it as my own account (as an admin user) <- could this be the problem?

- Definitely have friends on this account!

Thanks

- No JS errors, but the script tries to fetch